# Dimiss a UIViewController and be able to present/show it again with the same details - similar to Spotify "player view"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

In my application I have a (Master)`UIViewController`, with a `UITableView` holding audio files. When I select a cell a (Detail)`ViewController` is presented modally and plays the audio, and displays detail about the audio playing. 
Now, I want to dismiss the detail view and  still be able to present it afterwards with the same data displayed, kind of like multitasking or like Spotify "player" view behavior.

This is what I do when I dismiss:

```
@IBAction func dismissView(sender: AnyObject){ 
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true,completion:nil)
 }
```

In the (Master)`ViewController` I have a `UIView` as footer with a button to present the dismissed (Detail)`ViewController`.
And the way I present it is by hooking the button to the (Detail)`ViewController` using the Storyboard.

**EDIT: Attempting to build on my question with some advise from user** @JamesBlair

In my desperation to find a solution I've come to know that I need to save and restore the state of the (Detail)`ViewController` that's presented from (Master)`ViewController`.
However, when I read through the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW114) on `UIViewController` and `prepareForSegue`I don't understand how to implement this in the using segues.
Again, basically what I want is to dismiss the (Detail)`ViewController` which has `UIView` values, and be able to open it again with the same values.

I would really appreciate any help in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you dismiss your detail view controller, you should save the current state somewhere (disk, database, in-memory cache, etc).

Then override `prepareForSegue` when presenting the detail view controller, check to see if you have saved state for the item being presented, and pass it to the destination view controller if you do. The destination view controller can then display the saved state if it exists.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:

Comment: I see, this is very useful. But how do I check if the `ViewController` has a saved state in the `prepareForSegue`? Perhaps you could guide me with some sample code.